# how to set charset for php PDOException itself

Tags: php, pdo, encoding, character-encoding

I know how to set charset for database connection. 
But...how to configure charset for PDO itself .
ex. when php is running on windows(chinese) , if new PDO(...) failed, it will return message encoded by gbk.
If we want the error message is encoded by UTF-8 ,how ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exception messages encoded in UTF8 by changing the postgresql.conf directive as follows (example for french language) :

```
lc_messages = 'French_France.UTF-8'
```

Comment: thanks @Cyril Vazquez. for mysql ,I havn't found such config.